# Cannot find name 'figma' error on setting up Figma plugin

Tags: javascript, typescript, macos, figma, figma-api

I'm new to TS and JS.

Now I'm trying to set up my first plugin using [the guide](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/setup/) on macOS.

At some point I got an error:

```
/code.ts:9:1 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'figma'.
```

I followed all the steps from [the guide](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/setup/)

I suppose the next action in the Terminal.app should have solved the problem, but it did not

```
sudo npm install --save-dev @figma/plugin-typings
Password:
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/username/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/username/package.json'
npm WARN username No description
npm WARN username No repository field.
npm WARN username No README data
npm WARN username No license field.

+ @figma/plugin-typings@1.33.0
updated 1 package and audited 1 package in 2.72s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

The first line of "*.ts" code(except comments) looks like:

```
figma.showUI(__html__);
```

I write C++, Swift, Objective-C, some Java a lot and there are some include/import statements. But here is none. I don't know how to deal with it in TS at the moment. =(

PS
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run this command in a project directory.

Use:

```
cd <path to your project directory>
```

to change directory.
TIP: Print "cd ", simply drag and drop the project directory into the "Terminal.app" to not to print the full path manually.

Than:

```
npm install --save-dev @figma/plugin-typings
```

I did it in another directory. There is no info about it in [the guide](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/setup/#install-the-typings).